# How to run Node-Red on Docker with multiple environments with git

Tags: node-red, infrastructure-as-code, gitops

I'm running *Node-Red* on my server, and I want it to follow the deployment process like we are doing with code- working locally, making changes, commit and push.

Here is the list of the requirements:

- Run Node-Red on **Docker**.
- Track and backup tasks, configurations, all with ***Git***
- Ability to clone the repository and start Node-Red, **without any configurations**.
- Make the **changes on my local machine**, and deploy them by pushing to *Git*.

To be more accurate, I need to add the `flows.json`, `settings.json` and `package.json` to the git.

And one of the main issues is when I'm adding a new package to the `package.json`, the *NodeRed* will not install it automaticlly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (workaround) I found is based on adding `npm install` to the docker entrypoint, how does it work?

#### Mount to local folder

First, we want to run the *Node-Red*, and mount its `/data` volume to our local folder:

```
docker run -p 1880:1880 -v $(pwd)/node-red:/data nodered/node-red
```

Now, if you're running from your local *git repo*, you will get a folder called `node-red` and it will include all the *Node-Red* workspace.

#### Add *Node-Red* data to *Git*

To track only the *Node-Red* configuration files, you need to add the next entries to your `.gitignore` file:

```
node-red/*
!node-red/package.json
!node-red/package-lock.json
!node-red/flows.json
!node-red/flows_cred.json
!node-red/settings.js
```

All the other files are auto-generated.

#### Install the missing packages on startup

Now, the hard part. If you added a new library in your local environment, and you pushed the changes, you want *Node-Red* to install the new library before it starts.

We will take the original *Node-Red* start command from [Node-Red Dockerfile](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/blob/master/.docker/Dockerfile.alpine#L99):

```
npm --no-update-notifier --no-fund start --cache /data/.npm -- --userDir /data
```

And before this command, we will take the `npm install` command suggested for a [custom docker](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/docker#dockerfile-which-copies-in-local-resources):

```
npm install --unsafe-perm --no-update-notifier --no-fund --only=production
```

Here is my final `docker-compose.yml` file, which includes a `docker run` commandline to run only this image in the development environment:

```yaml
node-red:
  # port 1880
  # Dev: docker run -p 1880:1880 -v $(pwd)/node-red:/data --entrypoint="" --env-file .env nodered/node-red /bin/sh -c "npm install --prefix /data --unsafe-perm --no-update-notifier --no-fund --only=production && npm --no-update-notifier --no-fund start --cache /data/.npm -- --userDir /data"
  image: nodered/node-red
  env_file:
    - shared.env
  network_mode: host
  entrypoint: >
    sh -c "
    npm install --prefix /data --unsafe-perm --no-update-notifier --no-fund --only=production
    && npm --no-update-notifier --no-fund start --cache /data/.npm -- --userDir /data"
  environment:
    NODE_RED_CREDENTIAL_SECRET: ${NODE_RED_CREDENTIAL_SECRET}
  volumes:
    - ./node-red:/data
  restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the new (preview) feature called [Projects](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/projects/).

With this feature, the *Git* source control is integrated into your *Node-Red* instance, and shows you the changes, the missing packages, the commit history, and all.

To enable this feature, you need to [turn it on](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/projects/#enabling-projects) in the `settings.json` file.

Since it is a solution that is officially supported by *Node-Red* (in preview), it's highly recommended. AFAIK, it will not solve your problem to auto-install newly added packages, but on the other hand, it giving you a better control about what is changed, what needs to be installed, and what is missing, **in complex systems**.

Comment: Adding `autoInstallModules: true` to the `settings.js` will install any missing modules from the `package.json` in the Node-RED userDir

Comment: Are you sure? From my understanding (and testing) it will do that, only if it will see these packages are used in the `.config.nodes` file, and this file is shouldn't be backed up with git AFAIK.